# how change changed textview android

Tags: android, variables, button, android-intent

I passed the data from the first actvity (like `int VNIMANI` and `int OBRATNOST`). This data set my `TextView` after I came on second activity. now I need a button. And when I click on the button I need increment `+1`. But the code doesn't work.

```
TextView tvPaklic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paklic);
    String paklic = String.valueOf( + 10+ (VNIMANI+OBRATNOST));
    tvPaklic.setText(paklic);
}

int newPaklic = 0;
public void plusPaklic (View v){
    newPaklic = newPaklic + 1;
    displayPaklicDve (newPaklic);

}
private void displayPaklicDve(int newPaklic) {
    TextView tvpaklicdve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paklic);
    String paklicdve = String.valueOf(newPaklic);
    tvpaklicdve.setText(paklicdve);

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are these methods all in the same class? If not show the classes which contain each one. Also show where you set the event handler for your button.

Answer (score 0):

You were used 2 **Textview** objects with referring one id check that.

```
TextView tvPaklic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paklic);
TextView tvpaklicdve = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paklic);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to suggest you refer this one [Read this, will solve your problem](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string)